# How to build glfw.h as DLL

Tags: c++, opengl, dll

I'm new at OpenGL C++, and (omg this is being the hardest day i can remember) I'm still trying to get all the libraries of it on my Microsoft VS. The problem is with

```
glfw.h
```

because on [their page](http://www.glfw.org/release-2.7.7.html#compiling), its said i have to compile the file I've downloaded to get a DLL, but i have no idea how to do this... Its written to type this code into a CMD window on the path of the file:

> For example, one of the options is to compile GLFW for Windows using MinGW and MSYS. To do this, use:
>
> ```
>    *make win32-msys*
> ```
>
> This will compile the GLFW static library and DLL as well as the supplied example and test programs.

But its "not recognized as an internal system command".
So how do I do this?

Comment: Do you have [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) installed?

Comment: No .-. 
Wow how didn't I think about it? =s

Comment: Ok, i got it, now comes this step: To install GLFW on Cygwin (and possibly MinGW), run make with the cygwin-install target. This will generate the pkg-config file and copy it, the header file and the library to the correct locations of your Cygwin installation.

Comment: @Sunset: You know, you could just use the Visual Studio project files that ship with the distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions given are an example. The GLFW developers expect, that you know what development environment you use, which tools it ships with and how the gears and cogs fit together.

And quite frankly, I agree. You shouldn't do programming, without knowledge how the tools work under the hood. After all, you're doing things under the hood as well.

You're using Microsoft Visual Studio. The usual way to build projects there is through a so called *Solution*. Open that one, and start the build.

MinGW is a port of the open source GNU Compiler Collection and Binutils toolchain to windows. It's accompanied by MSys, a minimal set *nix like tools, a shell and among other things *make* . *make* is a tool for automatic dependency based file creation by command execution. Or in other words, a build system. The build process itself is controlled by a so called *Makefile* and defined in terms of *targets*, where *win32-mingw* is one of the targets GLFW's Makefile defines. However for a Visual C++ build it is the wrong target.

Solution to your problem, sorry to say it this blunt: You have to learn how to use your tools first.